# Hyper-V installation on Windows 8 CP with a DEP not being correctly recognized

Tags: windows-8-preview, hyper-v, data-execution-prevention

Seems like I am unable to add a Hyper-V Platform to Windows 8 Consumer Preview. Windows Feature addition dialog is reporting an error: "Hyper-V cannot be installed: Data Execution Prevention is not enabled".

DEP should be available on i7-975 Extreme Edition processors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on the Hardware Data Execution Prevention in your computer's BIOS for Hyper-V to be installed. It is NOT enough to turn on the settings from "My Computer" / Properties.